# New Relic "logs" folder is empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kubernetes, logging, newrelic

New Relic APM transactions have disappeared entirely for one of our microservices. Despite many days of looking we're at a loss to explain. The most significant clue: the `logs` folder is empty.

Do you know **what can cause the New Relic logs folder to be empty?**

More information:

1. ASP.NET Core 6 deployed to Kubernetes cluster (base `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal`). See [NR docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/install/dotnet/?deployment=linux&docker=yesDocker)
2. The same docker-image works fine in another cluster
3. A similar docker-image works fine in the same cluster
4. Normally, the `/usr/local/newrelic-netcore20-agent/logs` folder* has  these files:

   - NewRelic.Profiler.7.log
   - newrelic_agent_MyService.API.log

* Our path is custom. Default is `/usr/local/newrelic-dotnet-agent`

Answer (score 0):

Our situation was **resolved after we updated our microservice** however we still have no solid answers.

Here are some more notes that might help someone else in a similar situation...

The instrumenting APT package `libNewRelicProfiler.so` was not loaded, which would explain why no log files were created. But we could not explain why that package was not loaded. See [Step 2 of .NET Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/troubleshooting/debugging-net-core-agent-linux/#step-two).

The updated microservice (with logging that works) was launched with PID `8`, not the expected `7` which is typical.

The updated microservice uses .NET runtime 6.0.24 (was 6.0.22). Again, we had another similar microservice that used 6.0.22 without any problem and also, the same Docker image worked fine in another cluster.